# Copy/Paste Form Elements to new lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I may be over complicating this... I have a jQuery script that dynamically adds form elements to be used by the user :

```
var i=$('table tr').length;
$(".addmore").on('click',function(){
    addNewRow();
});

$(document).on('keypress', ".addNewRow", function(e){
    var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if(keyCode == 9 ) addNewRow();
});

var addNewRow = function(id){
    html = '<tr id="tr_'+i+'">';
    html += '<td><input class="case" id="caseNo_'+i+'" type="checkbox"/></td>';
    html += '<td class="prod_c"><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="data[InvoiceDetail]['+i+'][product_id]" id="itemNo_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">';
    html +='<span class="add_icon hide" id="add_icon_'+i+'"> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></span>';
    html +='</td>';

    html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="data[InvoiceDetail]['+i+'][productName]"  id="itemName_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="data[InvoiceDetail]['+i+'][price]" id="price_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';

    html += '<td><input type="text" name="data[InvoiceDetail]['+i+'][quantity]" id="quantity_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo quanyityChange" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">';
    html += '<input type="hidden" id="stock_'+i+'"/>';
    html += '<input type="hidden" id="stockMaintainer_'+i+'" name="data[InvoiceDetail]['+i+'][stockMaintainer]" />';
    html += '<input type="hidden" id="previousQuantity_'+i+'"/>';
    html += '<input type="hidden" id="invoiceDetailId_'+i+'"/>';
    html += '</td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" id="total_'+i+'" class="form-control totalLinePrice addNewRow" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="checkbox" name="data[InvoiceDetail][0][staged]" id="staged_1'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    html += '<td><select name="data[InvoiceDetail][0][location]" id="location_1'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">';
    html += '<option value="Used">Used</option>';
    html += '<option value="RTS">RTS</option>';
    html += '<option value="LAJ">LAJ</option>';
    html += '</select></td>';
    html += '</tr>';

    if( typeof id !== "undefined"){
        $('#tr_'+id).after(html);
    }else{
        $('table').append(html);
    }




    console.log(id);

    $('#caseNo_'+i).focus();

    i++;
}

//to check all checkboxes
$(document).on('change','#check_all',function(){
    $('input[class=case]:checkbox').prop("checked", $(this).is(':checked'));
});

//deletes the selected table rows
$(".delete").on('click', function() {
    $('.case:checkbox:checked').parents("tr").remove();
    $('#check_all').prop("checked", false); 
    calculateTotal();
});


$(document).on('blur','.autocomplete_txt',function(){
    //$('.add_icon').addClass('hide');
});

$(document).on('click','.add_icon',function(){
    var add_icon_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var add_icon_arr = add_icon_id.split("_");
    var icon_id = add_icon_arr[add_icon_arr.length-1];
    addNewRow(icon_id);
});
```

The result output puts a checkbox next to each line item, that you can use to delete items by line.  I want to be able to select multiple elements using the checkbox, and copy those form inputs,with the user entered data to "x" amount of rows depending on what is selected.

Does anyone know if it is possible to combine .clone() with .val() in jQuery to grab the input values, and copy them to new rows?  I have experimented with different ideas, and have not come up with anything that works yet... but then again, I am not well versed with jQuery.

Example Pic :
[image: Example Pic]

Snippet of output html from database call as requested by @Pluto :

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th width="2%"><input id="check_all" class="formcontrol" type="checkbox"/></th>
                                    <th width="20%">Item No</th>
                                    <th width="38%">Item Name</th>
                                    <th width="8%">Price</th>
                                    <th width="8%">Quantity</th>
                                    <th width="8%">Total</th>
                                    <th width="4%">Staged</th>
                                    <th width="12%">Location</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                                                                                            <tr id="tr_1">
                                            <td> <input class="case" type="checkbox"/> </td>
                                            <td class="prod_c">
                                                <input value="12VOLT:ALPINE:ALPINE AMPLIFIER:PDX-V9" type="text" data-type="productCode" name="data[InvoiceDetail][0][product_id]" id="itemNo_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">
                                                <span class="add_icon hide" id="add_icon_1"> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td><input value="5 Channel Power Density Digital Amplifier" type="text" data-type="productName" name="data[InvoiceDetail][0][productName]" id="itemName_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                                            <td><input value="351" type="number" name="data[InvoiceDetail][0][price]" id="price_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input value="1" type="number" name="data[InvoiceDetail][0][quantity]" id="quantity_1" class="form-control changesNo quanyityChange" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                                                <input value="1"  type="hidden" id="stock_1" autocomplete="off"/>
                                                <input value="0" type="hidden" id="stockMaintainer_1" name="data[InvoiceDetail][0][stockMaintainer]" autocomplete="off"/>
                                                <input value="1" type="hidden" id="previousQuantity_1" autocomplete="off"/>
                                                <input value="2817" type="hidden" id="invoiceDetailId_1" autocomplete="off"/>
                                            </td>
                                            <td><input value="351" type="number" id="total_1" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox"  data-type="checkbox" name="data[InvoiceDetail][0][staged]" id="staged_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                                            <td>
                                            <select value="" name="data[InvoiceDetail][0][location]" id="location_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">
                                                    <option value="Used" selected>Used</option>
                                                    <option value="RTS" >RTS</option>
                                                    <option value="LAJ" >LAJ</option>
                                            </select>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                            <tr id="tr_2">
                                            <td> <input class="case" type="checkbox"/> </td>
                                            <td class="prod_c">
                                                <input value="12VOLT:ALPINE:SPEAKERS-ALPINE:SPE-5000" type="text" data-type="productCode" name="data[InvoiceDetail][1][product_id]" id="itemNo_2" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">
                                                <span class="add_icon hide" id="add_icon_2"> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td><input value="Alpine Type E 5.25" type="text" data-type="productName" name="data[InvoiceDetail][1][productName]" id="itemName_2" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                                            <td><input value="41" type="number" name="data[InvoiceDetail][1][price]" id="price_2" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input value="1" type="number" name="data[InvoiceDetail][1][quantity]" id="quantity_2" class="form-control changesNo quanyityChange" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                                                <input value="6"  type="hidden" id="stock_2" autocomplete="off"/>
                                                <input value="0" type="hidden" id="stockMaintainer_2" name="data[InvoiceDetail][1][stockMaintainer]" autocomplete="off"/>
                                                <input value="1" type="hidden" id="previousQuantity_2" autocomplete="off"/>
                                                <input value="2818" type="hidden" id="invoiceDetailId_2" autocomplete="off"/>
                                            </td>
                                            <td><input value="41" type="number" id="total_2" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox"  data-type="checkbox" name="data[InvoiceDetail][1][staged]" id="staged_2" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                                            <td>
                                            <select value="" name="data[InvoiceDetail][1][location]" id="location_2" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">
                                                    <option value="Used" selected>Used</option>
                                                    <option value="RTS" >RTS</option>
                                                    <option value="LAJ" >LAJ</option>
                                            </select>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                            <tr id="tr_3">
                                            <td> <input class="case" type="checkbox"/> </td>
                                            <td class="prod_c">
                                                <input value="12VOLT:ALPINE:HEADUNIT-ALPINE:CDE-143BT" type="text" data-type="productCode" name="data[InvoiceDetail][2][product_id]" id="itemNo_3" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">
                                                <span class="add_icon hide" id="add_icon_3"> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td><input value="Cd/Usb Receiver W/Advanced Bluetooth By Alpine" type="text" data-type="productName" name="data[InvoiceDetail][2][productName]" id="itemName_3" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                                            <td><input value="93" type="number" name="data[InvoiceDetail][2][price]" id="price_3" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input value="1" type="number" name="data[InvoiceDetail][2][quantity]" id="quantity_3" class="form-control changesNo quanyityChange" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                                                <input value="0"  type="hidden" id="stock_3" autocomplete="off"/>
                                                <input value="0" type="hidden" id="stockMaintainer_3" name="data[InvoiceDetail][2][stockMaintainer]" autocomplete="off"/>
                                                <input value="1" type="hidden" id="previousQuantity_3" autocomplete="off"/>
                                                <input value="2819" type="hidden" id="invoiceDetailId_3" autocomplete="off"/>
                                            </td>
                                            <td><input value="93" type="number" id="total_3" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-type="checkbox" name="data[InvoiceDetail][2][staged]" id="staged_3" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                                            <td>
                                            <select value="" name="data[InvoiceDetail][2][location]" id="location_3" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">
                                                    <option value="Used" >Used</option>
                                                    <option value="RTS" selected>RTS</option>
                                                    <option value="LAJ" >LAJ</option>
                                            </select>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                            <tr id="tr_4">
                                            <td> <input class="case" type="checkbox"/> </td>
                                            <td class="prod_c">
                                                <input value="12VOLT:ALPINE:SPEAKERS-ALPINE:SPE-5000" type="text" data-type="productCode" name="data[InvoiceDetail][3][product_id]" id="itemNo_4" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">
                                                <span class="add_icon hide" id="add_icon_4"> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td><input value="Alpine Type E 5.25" type="text" data-type="productName" name="data[InvoiceDetail][3][productName]" id="itemName_4" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                                            <td><input value="41" type="number" name="data[InvoiceDetail][3][price]" id="price_4" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input value="1" type="number" name="data[InvoiceDetail][3][quantity]" id="quantity_4" class="form-control changesNo quanyityChange" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                                                <input value="6"  type="hidden" id="stock_4" autocomplete="off"/>
                                                <input value="0" type="hidden" id="stockMaintainer_4" name="data[InvoiceDetail][3][stockMaintainer]" autocomplete="off"/>
                                                <input value="1" type="hidden" id="previousQuantity_4" autocomplete="off"/>
                                                <input value="2820" type="hidden" id="invoiceDetailId_4" autocomplete="off"/>
                                            </td>
                                            <td><input value="41" type="number" id="total_4" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-type="checkbox" name="data[InvoiceDetail][3][staged]" id="staged_4" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                                            <td>
                                            <select value="" name="data[InvoiceDetail][3][location]" id="location_4" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">
                                                    <option value="Used" >Used</option>
                                                    <option value="RTS" >RTS</option>
                                                    <option value="LAJ" selected>LAJ</option>
                                            </select>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                            <tr id="tr_5">
                                            <td> <input class="case" type="checkbox"/> </td>
                                            <td class="prod_c">
                                                <input value="12VOLT:ALPINE:HEADUNIT-ALPINE:CDE-143BT" type="text" data-type="productCode" name="data[InvoiceDetail][4][product_id]" id="itemNo_5" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">
                                                <span class="add_icon hide" id="add_icon_5"> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td><input value="Cd/Usb Receiver W/Advanced Bluetooth By Alpine" type="text" data-type="productName" name="data[InvoiceDetail][4][productName]" id="itemName_5" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                                            <td><input value="93" type="number" name="data[InvoiceDetail][4][price]" id="price_5" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input value="1" type="number" name="data[InvoiceDetail][4][quantity]" id="quantity_5" class="form-control changesNo quanyityChange" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                                                <input value="0"  type="hidden" id="stock_5" autocomplete="off"/>
                                                <input value="0" type="hidden" id="stockMaintainer_5" name="data[InvoiceDetail][4][stockMaintainer]" autocomplete="off"/>
                                                <input value="1" type="hidden" id="previousQuantity_5" autocomplete="off"/>
                                                <input value="2821" type="hidden" id="invoiceDetailId_5" autocomplete="off"/>
                                            </td>
                                            <td><input value="93" type="number" id="total_5" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox"  data-type="checkbox" name="data[InvoiceDetail][4][staged]" id="staged_5" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                                            <td>
                                            <select value="" name="data[InvoiceDetail][4][location]" id="location_5" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">
                                                    <option value="Used" selected>Used</option>
                                                    <option value="RTS" >RTS</option>
                                                    <option value="LAJ" >LAJ</option>
                                            </select>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                            <tr id="tr_6">
                                            <td> <input class="case" type="checkbox"/> </td>
                                            <td class="prod_c">
                                                <input value="" type="text" data-type="productCode" name="data[InvoiceDetail][5][product_id]" id="itemNo_6" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">
                                                <span class="add_icon hide" id="add_icon_6"> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td><input value="" type="text" data-type="productName" name="data[InvoiceDetail][5][productName]" id="itemName_6" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                                            <td><input value="0" type="number" name="data[InvoiceDetail][5][price]" id="price_6" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input value="0" type="number" name="data[InvoiceDetail][5][quantity]" id="quantity_6" class="form-control changesNo quanyityChange" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                                                <input value=""  type="hidden" id="stock_6" autocomplete="off"/>
                                                <input value="0" type="hidden" id="stockMaintainer_6" name="data[InvoiceDetail][5][stockMaintainer]" autocomplete="off"/>
                                                <input value="0" type="hidden" id="previousQuantity_6" autocomplete="off"/>
                                                <input value="2822" type="hidden" id="invoiceDetailId_6" autocomplete="off"/>
                                            </td>
                                            <td><input value="0" type="number" id="total_6" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox"  data-type="checkbox" name="data[InvoiceDetail][5][staged]" id="staged_6" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                                            <td>
                                            <select value="" name="data[InvoiceDetail][5][location]" id="location_6" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">
                                                    <option value="Used" >Used</option>
                                                    <option value="RTS" >RTS</option>
                                                    <option value="LAJ" >LAJ</option>
                                            </select>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                            <tr id="tr_7">
                                            <td> <input class="case" type="checkbox"/> </td>
                                            <td class="prod_c">
                                                <input value="" type="text" data-type="productCode" name="data[InvoiceDetail][6][product_id]" id="itemNo_7" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">
                                                <span class="add_icon hide" id="add_icon_7"> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td><input value="" type="text" data-type="productName" name="data[InvoiceDetail][6][productName]" id="itemName_7" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                                            <td><input value="0" type="number" name="data[InvoiceDetail][6][price]" id="price_7" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input value="0" type="number" name="data[InvoiceDetail][6][quantity]" id="quantity_7" class="form-control changesNo quanyityChange" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                                                <input value=""  type="hidden" id="stock_7" autocomplete="off"/>
                                                <input value="0" type="hidden" id="stockMaintainer_7" name="data[InvoiceDetail][6][stockMaintainer]" autocomplete="off"/>
                                                <input value="0" type="hidden" id="previousQuantity_7" autocomplete="off"/>
                                                <input value="2823" type="hidden" id="invoiceDetailId_7" autocomplete="off"/>
                                            </td>
                                            <td><input value="0" type="number" id="total_7" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox"  data-type="checkbox" name="data[InvoiceDetail][6][staged]" id="staged_7" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                                            <td>
                                            <select value="" name="data[InvoiceDetail][6][location]" id="location_7" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">
                                                    <option value="Used" >Used</option>
                                                    <option value="RTS" >RTS</option>
                                                    <option value="LAJ" >LAJ</option>
                                            </select>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                                                                                </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: It is not very clear to me what you want to do, it is a good idea to make a fiddle when you have a question about js.

Comment: I've create a jsfiddle based on the user's code, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/sjpjaeu0/

Comment: @Pluto Thank you very much for helping me describe my issue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just storing the names and values? Here's an example that would do the job:

```
function getValues(id){
    var inputs=$('#tr_'+id).find('select,input,textarea').filter('[name]');
    var values={};
    for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++){
        var cur=inputs[i];
        // Get the end of the name attribute, to leave out the unique id/index
        values[cur.name.match(/\[\w+]$/)||cur.name] = $(cur).is(':checkbox, :radio') ? cur.checked : cur.value;
    }
    return values;
}
function setValues(id,values){
    var inputs=$('#tr_'+id);
    for(var i in values){
        var cur=inputs.find('[name$="'+i+'"]');
        if(cur.is(':checkbox, :radio')) {
            cur.prop('checked', values[i]);
        } else {
            cur.val(values[i]);
        }
    }
}
//copies the selected table rows to new ones
$(".copy").on('click', function() {
    var origs=$('.case:checkbox:checked');
    for(var a=0; a<origs.length; a++) {
        // Places copy at end
        addNewRow();
        var arr = origs.closest('tr')[a].id.split('_');
        var id = arr[arr.length-1];
        var dat = getValues(id);
        setValues(i-1, dat);
    }
    $('#check_all').add(origs).prop("checked", false);
});
```

I set it up to take ID's so that you can choose where you want the row inserted/data copied to. For now, it just copies the values to rows added at the end.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/y68wuj08/1/

Comment: The one problem with my example is if you have multiple radio buttons or checkboxes of the same name (which is valid HTML), it doesn't use their value attributes to filter which one to make checked. That can be fixed but your code only seems to use individual checkboxes (not checkbox groups).

Comment: That works great for copying current elements the user has just entered(for the session), but I would like to copy prior saved elements.  If you try this with your code, it just copys blank lines...  However, so far, this is the closest solution so far :)

Comment: Could you edit the jsfiddle to show what it looks like when there are prior elements? I thought they were going to be identical to newly entered ones.

Comment: The "prior elements" are simply data loaded from a sql database to fill the form fields. I can post the php code if you like.

Comment: That would work, though a snippet of the resulting HTML would be best.

Comment: I added the snippet to my main question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88845/discussion-between-steven-and-pluto).

Answer (score 0):

As @Pluto points out below I didn't solve the problem. I edited to at least reverse the array properly, though, and this was a fun little foray into jQuery since it'd been a while.

```
$.fn.reverse = [].reverse; //why doesn't jQuery just do this anyway?
$("button.copy").on('click', function(){
    var cases = $("input.case:checkbox:checked");
    var last = cases.last().closest("tr");
    cases.reverse().each(function(index){
        var newRow = $(this).closest("tr").clone();
        last.after(newRow);
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem with using `.clone()` is that it copies unique id's so there are duplicates of them.